# Is it possible to iterate through multiple cameras using OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I want to iterate through multiple cameras that I have. I want to iterate through the cameras, display live video feed from the camera, and if a certain condition is met, break the loop of this camera and start viewing in the next camera.

```
import cv2
import itertools
counter = 0
cams = [0,1]

for cam in itertools.cycle(cams):
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam)
    
    if cap.isOpened():
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                print(cam, "     ", counter)
                counter =+ 1
                cv2.imshow("FRAME", frame)
                if counter == 10 or cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
    else:
        continue
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this is what I have tried.

Comment: Ok, and what's the problem with current code?

Comment: it doesn't work, there is no increment in the counter

Comment: Use `counter += 1` rather than `counter =+ 1`